# BindingSource remove current

Tags: c#

I use BindingSource for deleting records in my forms:

```
try
{
    BindingSource1.RemoveCurrent();
    BindingSource1.EndEdit();
    Table1TableAdapter.Update(dataSet01.Table1);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.show(ex.Message);
}
```

if record related to another,at first user see this record remove,but after that an error will arise. How can I prevent removing related record at first; so no error will be shown.

Comment: "but after that an error will arise." What error? Is it a foreign key contraint violation? Can you post the error message? Can you post information about your table structure?

Comment: yes, error is foreign key contraint violation.

Answer (score 4):

```
try
{
    BindingSource1.RemoveCurrent();
    BindingSource1.EndEdit();
    Table1TableAdapter.Update(dataSet01.Table1);
    dataSet01.Table1.AcceptChanges(); <====== add this
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can for example load an hidden column in your grid that contains the reference to the related record, if the field is not null you have to implement the logic to avoid deletion of the record, and prevent the error.